# Is there a music application that integrates with iTunes and shows the waveform of the song?

Tags: software-recommendation, music

I am looking for a music applications that integrates with my iTunes library and plays songs something like this:

[image: SoundCloud screenshot]
Playing a song:
[image: SoundCloud screenshot 2]

<sup><sub>Screenshots from [SoundCloud.](http://soundcloud.com/)</sub></sup>

I really want to be able to play a song, see the waveform and be able to skip in the song. Is there such an application?

Comment: Vanilla iTunes, while it doesn't show the waveform, it _does_ let you jump to any location by clicking on the little how-far-along indicator in the top of the app window.  I right-click on the song, show in finder, then open the file in Audacity or Amadeus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[djay](http://www.algoriddim.com/djay-mac) is what I was looking for. I really like it, as it integrates with your iTunes library, and auto-updates when you add new songs to your library. It has a visual waveform, as well as a vinyl representation of the song, which allows you to move a needle around on the record, skipping from place to place in the song.

[image]

It *is* $19.99 [on the Mac app store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/djay/id411699771?mt=12&ls=1), but it is packed with great features!

Comment: And I'll add that there's an awesome iPhone/iPad version that rocks!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [Capo](http://supermegaultragroovy.com/products/Capo/)? I have the iPad version, and it does what you want. I assume the desktop version does the same.

Comment: I do like Capo, but it doesn't integrate with iTunes :-( See my new answer on this question.